# Issues with same web service under different app pools

Tags: iis, application-pool

I recently discovered that one of my server machines had the same service under different Web Sites and they were managed by different app pools. Something like this:

- Custom Web Site

  - MyWebSite (Managed by CustomAppPool v4)
- Default Web Site

  - MyWebSite (Managed by Default App Pool v4)

The CustomWebSite version is hit on http 28000 port. The default one is just set up on 80 (this is not really hit)

Both the Web Sites are pointing to C:\inetpub\wwwroot. The Default Web Site version should not have been converted to an application in the first place. My question is how bad is it? Should I be separating the service asap?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that IIS will handle the requests independently, so there should not be any danger in sharing code files. Other than it being untidy and allowing potential process issues, I don't think you have to remove it. On the same token, I believe you would be fine to remove it.

Comment: I am trying to find some evidence to back this up. My answer comes from having many funky IIS setups in the past, and I feel like I've run into this before and simply removing the default website did not affect the custom website.